# Install latest compatible version of package with pip

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I'm trying to install NumPy with PIP 9.0.1 (Python 3.3):

```
/opt/python/cp33-cp33m/bin/pip install 'numpy<2,>=1.7'
```

PIP merrily gathers numpy-1.12 and then dies because numpy-1.11 is the last version that supported Python 3.3.

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.12.1.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-4jvhwz/numpy/setup.py", line 34, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.")
    RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.
```

How can I have pip install the latest compatible version of a package?

Naturally, I could figure this out manually. But this code's in a batch script with a large number of Python distributions (I'm building manylinux wheels), so only a programmatic solution is suitable.

Comment: `pip` already installs the latest compatible version it can select. The additional check occurs in `numpy`s setup script, and there's nothing `pip` can do about it. This situation depicts one of the reasons the wheel format was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

There may not be a way to have PIP does this automagically, but one can use strings like the following to restrict what is installed for particular versions of Python:

```
numpy>=1.7,<2; python_version > '3.4'
numpy>=1.7,<1.12; python_version < '3.4'
```

Further details are [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers).